# Why is React loading failover img src if WebP is supported in Firefox?

Tags: html, reactjs, webp

My understanding is that given the following code, only the `*.webp` image should be loaded.

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="macos-1920x1080.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="macos-1920x1080.png" alt="..." width="100%">
</picture>
```

But somehow, [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app)'s loads `macos-1920x1080.png`, and then `macos-1920x1080.webp` when I start app using `npm start` (everything works as expected when using `npm run build` and serving app using Express).

Comment: A similar [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20682) has been reported on the React repo.